# Obtain Media Statistics for local Video File - VLC ANDROID

Tags: android, video, statistics, vlc, libvlc

How would I go about obtaining media statistics for a particular video file and dump them to the log?

The exact `struct` I need access to is: `libvlc_media_stats_t` Struct Reference.

The documentation for this struct was generated from the following file:
[`include/vlc/libvlc_media.h`](http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/structlibvlc__media__stats__t.html#details).

I cannot find the `libvlc_media.h` file when I open up the project in Eclipse. Please advise on how I could get the Media Statistics that I need from this function.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using C, you would have to proceed that way to get information from a media:

```
// Create VLC instance and media
libvlc_instance_t * inst = libvlc_new (0, NULL);
libvlc_media_t* media = libvlc_media_new_path (inst, /* media path here */);  

// Get stats from media
libvlc_media_stats_t stats;
int stat =  libvlc_media_get_stats(media, &stats);

// Obtain stats one by one
int bytes = stats.i_read_bytes;
float = stats.f_input_bitrate;
int = stats.i_demux_read_bytes;
float = stats.f_demux_bitrate;
int = stats.i_demux_corrupted;
int = stats.i_demux_discontinuity;
int = stats.i_decoded_video;
```

However, be careful: I have seen [some messages](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=99890) on VLC forums saying that this part of the library may be broken. That said, some [more recent messages](http://malkman36.appspot.com/forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&p=373528&sid=784b6338b805aa780d89f61b39524475) on that same forum seem to say that the library works well. One message says you may need to have the media playing in order to get its statistics (there are information you can't get in libvlc if the media is not playing).

Comment: Could you expand on this? I still can't seem to get any statistics of the video playing. I know it is possible on the desktop version of VLC. But can it be done on android-vlc?

Comment: @user2031263 I fear I won't be able to help you there. I somehow know how to use libvlc (at least some parts of it), but I don't have any experience with Android.